# How to Connect Azure IoT Hub Stream Data to PowerBI and SQL Database

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub

I am going through the Adafruit Huzzah Microsoft IoT [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-huzzah-esp8266-get-started) and the PowerBI [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-power-bi). However, I am having some issues. I have connected my Huzzah to an IoT Hub using the first tutorial link. Then' I have followed another tutorial to stream the messages that the devices send to the IoT Hub as JSON files into a Blob Container.

What I want to do two things:

- Stream my IoT Hub into a SQL Database. The issue is that I don't know how to create a table for my Database.
- Stream my IoT Hub into PowerBI service. I don't see my hub there to connect.

Can anyone guide me with this?